# Length between iterators in size_type

Tags: c++, iterator, difference, size-type

I am writing custom algorithm and at some point it needs to get distance between two iterators. If I assume that `it1` < `it2` I can get positive distance (`it2 - it1`) between them. This is okay, but `std::distance` and `operator-` returns `difference_type` that (in my case) is an alias to `long long`. What if the distance is too big to fit in `long long` but will fit inside `unsigned long long` (in my case its `size_type` alias)?
For this example I also assume `long long` is `int64_t` and `unsigned long long` is `uint64_t`:

```
std::string container = ...; // assume enourmous number of characters, like 2^64 - 1024
std::cout << (container.begin() - container.end());
```

Since `operator-` returns `difference_type`, that cannot fit `2^64 - 1024` it should print negative number (in fact anything - it is UB) due to overflow. Of course I can cast it back to `std::string::size_type` but I can't be sure whether previous undefined behaviour worked as I assumed. How can I deal with such issue?

Comment: Can't you store the distance in a variable of type `difference_type` ? I mean you can work on a template based solution to cover all cases.

Comment: In my not so humble oppinion, if you have such large datasets that you need an unsigned 64-bit integer for the "distance" between two elements, then you're using the wrong data-structures or the wrong design.

Comment: Its not that I will have so much data. I just want to know what would be the possible solution. I don't want my algorithm to work "most of cases". I can leave it using conversions but it will be viable to data overflow :/

Comment: How much would 2^64 memory cost, and will any of your customers be able to dedicate it to a single container in your program?

Comment: This problem is really simple, if you have a C++11 compiler. Just use `auto` :)

Comment: If you have that much data, you shouldn't really use standard C++ containers, and therefore it won't be a problem.

Comment: Well, okay... I don't have that much data, it is just a hypothetical question - what if.

Comment: As long as you know that `std::distance` should be positive `static_cast<size_t>(distance)` should give you correct index

Comment: @KillzoneKid I mentioned this. I would have to assume that signed overflow is causing rollback to negative values and this is poor assumption. Signed overflow has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never be an issue. We know this because of [`max_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size) which is expressed in as a `size_t`. The return of `max_size` represents:

> The maximum number of elements the `string` is able to hold due to system or library implementation limitations, i.e. ​`std::distance(begin(), end())`​ for the largest string

Thus iterators to a `string` separated by greater than `size_t` is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

> [..] What if the distance is too big to fit in [`distance_type`] but will fit inside [some other type] [..]
>
> How can I deal with such issue?

You cannot. It's the job of whoever implemented the container as well as the corresponding iterator.

If the type they used for the distance cannot fit all values that could occur with the container then that's a bug in the container.

Clarification: `difference_type` actually [depends on the iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) used.

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation on how I would have tackled the problem.

Let's leave it to the type-deduction system to make the right call.

**Pre C++11 implementation -**

```
template<typename It>
void distance_algo_impl(It const & begin, It const & end)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type distance
        = std::distance(begin, end);

    std::cout << "\ndistance :" << distance << "\n";
    // ... do your distance based algorithm here
}

template<typename T>
void distance_algo(T const & container)
{
    distance_algo_impl(container.begin(), container.end());
}
```

**Post C++11 Implementation -**

```
template<typename T>
void distance_algo(T const & container)
{
    auto distance = std::distance(container.begin(), container.end());
    std::cout << "\ndistance :" << distance << "\n";
    // ... do your distance based algorithm here
}
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking for. I know that type deduction can "work" but this does not solve problem of converting signed -> unsigned.

Comment: Well I was not clear on what you desired. If you need the capacity of `unsigned` datatype, with the flexibility of signed datatype, I would recommend you to create a new type of your own. A new type which would be a pair of `<bool, unsigned>` . If you want, I can sketch a sample app that would work with the new datatype. The `bool` will store the information of sign, while the `unsigned` part of the pair would store the magnitude.